# undefined reference to wl_dispatch_display_que_pending

Tags: gcc, gtk, undefined-reference

I am new to gtk+ and I'm trying to put a window on the screen using gtk3. My source file is win.c and I have tried to compile it using

```
$ gcc win.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -o win.o
```

but what I get is:

```
/lib64/libEGL.so.1: undefined reference to `wl_display_dispatch_queue_pending'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following command :

```
yum update libwayland*
```

Answer (score 0):

wl_display_dispatch_queue_pending seems related to Wayland, the protocol implemented by successors of the Xorg server. The question is: why are you building for Wayland ?